# Isomorphism between kernels of R-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> If $f,g:M\to M$ are homomorphisms of $R$-modules is it true that $\ker(g\circ f)/\ker(f)\simeq \ker(g)$?

The morphism

$$\ker(g\circ f)\to \ker(g), \ x\mapsto f(x),$$

has kernel equal to $\ker(f)$. But I don't see the surjectivity.

Thanks you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the situation in which $R$ is a field, $M$ is a finite dimensional vector space, $g=0$ and $f$ is any non-surjective linear map ---for example, $f=0$.

Comment: Ohhh, thanks.--